# Who is being pleased, and why?

Tags: phrases, politeness

This is more of a curiosity than a full problem, but I was wondering who is being pleased, in common phrases using the term.

> (At breakfast)
>
> > “May I have some jam, please?”

In this case the jam-wisher is the pleasee, and the jam-scooper is the pleaser.

> (At a party)
>
> > “May I please enter?”

The entrant is pleased, and the host is pleaser.

In both questions, it is easy to see who is being pleased, and how, but from context, not from the position or conjugation of the word

> (At royal court)
>
> > If it pleases the lord, we shall host a fête tonight.

[if it please* the lord?/sic]

In this case, the question is not posed by somebody looking to be pleased, but a courtier on behalf of a pleasee, in other words, is it then the pleaser asking please? Here the question may be perfunctory, but the format implies an option to cancel, does please work the same from both ends of the transaction?

> (At the airport)
>
> > “If you please, place your items in the basket.

There is no doubt here, and there is no alternative. If you don’t please, you may not be able to proceed.

Is there a set of rules for using please, or is it really just a softening phrase when otherwise using imperatives?

Answer (score 2):

*Please* is short for *if you please.* The literal meaning would be that the person need only pass the jam, or let the guest in, if they are pleased to do so. In fact, of course, it's just a polite way of making a request. Similarly with the airport notice; you have to do it, but they are asking nicely.

Comment: Yes, it's a reduced fixed phrase, which can be used instead, but is more formal. And as an independent utterance, it can go in practically any niche available in the sentence, which is likely to be a request or an order.